# PHP Contact Form Error on Line 7

Tags: php, html

I'm fairly new to PHP but have used HTMl and CSS for 3 years now.

I apparently have an error on line 10 mail

```
($to, $subject, $message, "From: " $name . $email);
```

Full code:

PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$to = "jamiemeechan@outlook.com";
$subject = "Email from Tropilac.com"
mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " $name . $email);
echo "Your message has been sent";
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="/scripts/contact.php" method="post" name="contact">
<p>Name:</p>
<input name="name" type="text"/>
<p>Email:</p>
<input name="email" type="text"/>
<p>Messgae:</p>
<textarea name="messgae" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send!"/>
<input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
```

Yes I have the PHP file in a folder called scripts.

Comment: `"From: " $name` You're missing a `.` if that's meant to be concatenation.

Comment: Even with the missing dot, the `From:` will fail. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Do I change my line to: bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good spot. I skimmed and thought it was the body variable *facepalm*.

Comment: @JonStirling (wink)

Comment: Which variable? @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred-ii- wanted to add an answer...